# Change auth credentials in KTor client

Tags: ktor

How can I change the credentials in a KTor client?

The Auth feature needs to be installed when the client is created. I've tried doing it later but it seems not to work, either as a first time setup or a repeat.

The docs suggest holding onto the client once it's created as the setup is expensive, so it seems unduly restrictive not to be able to change the credentials (& surely the smart folks at JetBrains wouldn't have done that).

I have an answer which works, to my surprise, but I'm not sure it's a good answer. Comments welcome.

Because the docs say that creating the client is expensive I've put it in a singleton and then I've done something like this

```
@ThreadLocal
Object ServerLink {
    fun setClient(id:String, pw:String) {
        // Create the client here and set id and pw
    }
}
```

Then I simply call ServerLink.setClient(newId, newPW) whenever I want. Yes this works, and I didn't think I'd got multiple threads, but won't this be a memory leak, or at least memory waste?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by getting a reference to `Auth` feature and mutating its list of providers. Here is an example of changing Basic authentication credentials after client creation:

```
val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
    install(Auth) {
        basic {
            username = "user"
            password = "password"
        }
    }
}

val auth = client.feature(Auth)
if (auth != null) {
    auth.providers.removeAt(0)
    auth.basic {
        username = "new-user"
        password = "new-password"
    }
}

val r = client.get<String>("http://httpbin.org/basic-auth/new-user/new-password")
println(r)
```

Comment: This looks right but doesn't work for me. I wonder if it's because my client is in a Kotlin singleton. To my surprise I do have an answer, I've added it to the question, but I'm not sure it's a good one.

Answer (score 0):

With ktor version 2.2.1 I managed to update the bearer token credentials like this:

```
   const val REFRESH_TOKEN = "" // not required

   val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
     Auth {
        bearer {
            sendWithoutRequest { true }
            loadTokens { BearerTokens(initialToken, REFRESH_TOKEN) }
        }
     }
   }

   fun updateBearerCredentials(newToken: String) {
      client.plugin(Auth).bearer {
        loadTokens { BearerTokens(newToken, REFRESH_TOKEN) }
      }
   }
```

I assume the same works for basic auth. Have not tested it though.